# linear time algorithm for finding most frequent m-letter substring in a string

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, suffix-tree, suffix-array

Suppose we have a n letter string and we are searching for most repeated m letter substring (1=<m =< n).
I am just searching for an algorithm which solves this problem in linear time. And I have reached to suffix tree. But how can I solve it by suffix tree?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

#### Idea

You can also solve it with hash function.

We can convert strings to base `b` numbers where `b` is a prime number.

For example, if the strings only consist of lowercase alphabet (26 characters `a-z`) then we can choose `b` equals `29`.

Then we map string characters to corresponding numbers. For example:

```
a -> 1
b -> 2
c -> 3
...
z -> 26
```

String `abc` will equals `29^2*1 + 29^1*2 + 29^0*3 = 899` in base `29`.

We should map `a -> 1` but not `a -> 0` since hash value of `aaa` and `aa` will be equal in base `b`, which shouldn't be.

Now instead of compare two strings, we can compares their hash value in base `b`. If their hash value are equal then we can say they are equal.

Since hash value can be very large, you can use it's module a large prime number, for example `mod 1e9+7`. The posibility of two different strings have same hash value is very low in this case.

#### Algorithm

The algorithm can be described as bellow:

```
Let n-letter string be S
Let hash(s) be function to get hash value of string s
For each m-letter-substring of S, call it s
   Increase the number of occurrences of hash(s), let call its o(hash(s))
Result will be the m-letter-substring s with the maximum o(hash(s))
```

To calculate `hash(s)`, first we build array `H` where:

```
H[i] = (b^(i-1)*S[1] + b^(i-2)*S[2] + b^(i-3)*S[3] + ... + b^0*S[i]) % mod
```

Here `S[i]` is the mapped number of character i-th of string S.

To calculate `b^x`, we can calculate array `powb` where:

```
powb[0] = 1; powb[i] = (powb[i - 1] * b) % mod
```

Then for a substring `s[l..r]` of string S,

```
hash(s[l..r]) = (H[r] - H[l-1]*b^(r-l+1)) % mod
```

As we can see, `hash(s)` can be negative, in this case we should add `mod` to `hash(s)` (`hash(s) += mod`).

#### Complexity

```
O(N) to calculate H, powb
O(N) to iterate every substring s
  For each s
    O(1) to calculate hash(s)
    O(log(N)) to calculate total occurrences of hash value (C++ map)

Total complexity: O(N log N)
```